# Consuming API on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, rest

I'm trying to create a web application which has no database of its own, but rather gets its data from an API.

This API isn't necessarily RESTful so I'm using [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to make calls.

I am getting the data (JSON) perfectly but deserializing it is a bit tricky for nested objects.

The question is: **Should I deserialize the objects with custom deserializers for each of them who have nested objects or just work with the hash I get from JSON.parse(string)?**

Note that html.erb code will look like <%= hash['id'] %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse should be enough. I would create a PORO (Plain old ruby object) if I need to pass the data received from the API around the App, but you should start small and just use JSON.parse for now.